# Djangorestframework returns: TypeError: get_extra_actions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when declaring get()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am a little confused in my code I have:

```py
from django.db.models import query
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Publication
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializer import PublicationSerializer

# Create your views here.

class PublicationView(APIView):
    
    serial_class = PublicationSerializer()

    def get_extra_actions(self):
        return [ self.get() ]

    def get(self, request):
        detail = [ {'pub_id': i.pub_id, 'pub_date': i.pub_date, 'title': i.title, 'description': i.description, 'link': i.link} for i in Publication.objects.all() ]
        return Response(detail)
```

but I am still getting a return the above error. Any thoughts or help? Let me know!

Comment: I think it's because in get_extra_actions you are missing the request parameter when calling self.get() in the return statement

Comment: Unfortunately, I it is not as simple as that :( when I do that it also says that `get_extra_actions(self) missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little bit of research I found that using APIview was not really what I needed. using the `viewsets.ModelViewSet` was much simpler and led to just two lines of code.

```py
class PublicationView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = PublicationSerializer
   queryset = Publication.objects.all()
```

After routing the api back to `urls.py` everything works perfectly!